# How can I determine user base page limit for a printer?

Tags: cups, quota, printer

I'm using Debian Linux. I want to determine user base page limit, different page limit for different users, for a printer.

I can determine page limit for printer with CUPS but can not determine page limit for single user.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps you could show how you're determining these things currently? It's a little difficult to understand what you're asking for.

Comment: I want to manage printer page quota and i want to do this user base. For example we have an office that have one printer which is name "Printer A" and two person names "slm" and "ibasaran". Slm can print 10 page and ibasaran can print 20 page a day via Printer A. With CUPS we can determine page limit but it is not user base it is printer base. For example we can determine anybody can print 10 page a day with CUPS. https://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.7/accounting.html?VERSION=1.7&Q=#QUOTAS

Comment: I'm also trying to do that, and from what I understand quota per user is not achievable natively. So I'm on my way to try Pykota (http://www.pykota.com/software/pykota/). Just in case you didn't know about it...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `job-page-limit` option along with the `-U username` option of `lpadmin` print configuration command.

From the manpage:

```
-o job-page-limit=value
Sets the page limit for per-user quotas. 
The value is the integer number of pages that can be printed; 
double-sided pages are counted as two pages.
```

To set this limit per day you can use `job-quota-period`:

```
-o job-quota-period=value
Sets the accounting period for per-user quotas. 
The value is an integer number of seconds; 86,400 seconds are in one day.
```

Comment: I already tried -U username but nothing changed. This link says "CUPS supports page and size-based quotas for each printer. The quotas are tracked individually for each user, but a single set of limits applies to all users for a particular printer. For example, you can limit every user to 5 pages per day on an expensive printer, but you cannot limit every user except Johnny." https://www.cups.org/documentation.php/doc-1.7/accounting.html?VERSION=1.7&Q=#QUOTAS